# How to use $SHELL?

Tags: bash, zsh, bash-scripting

I'm trying to determine if the person running my script is in a bash shell or zsh (or gitbash).

I thought I could do something like this:

```
  if [ $SHELL == *"zsh"* ]; then
    THIS_SHELL="zsh"
  elif [ $SHELL == *"bash"* ] || [ $0 = "/usr/bin/bash" ]; then
    THIS_SHELL="bash"
  fi
```

But there's something I don't understand:

```
ALT02884% echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
ALT02884% if [ $SHELL == *"zsh"* ]; then
then> echo "yes"
then> else
else> echo "no"
else> fi
zsh: = not found
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I needed to add another set of square brackets to my test:

```
if [[ $SHELL == *"zsh"* ]]; then
    THIS_SHELL="zsh"
  elif [[ $SHELL == *"bash"* ]]; then
    THIS_SHELL="bash"
  fi
```

Here is an explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542854/226473